# Перевод для "XOXO"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

По результатам недавнего (пару недель) падения серверов SO обнаружились ошибки локализации. Был создан [баг репорт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290372/339911) на Meta.SE. На текущий момент он исправлен частично, и как раз по готовой части хотелось бы провести обсуждение.

> [image: хохо]

Вот это `XOXO,` имеет смысл как-то локализовать. В оригинале это вроде как некий [сленговский термин](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=xoxo) для обозначения "обнимашек и целовашек".

Совсем немного обсуждение из чата может быть обнаружено [тут](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35060696#35060696). А более года назад даже [упоминалось](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=25935406#25935406) одним из действующих модераторов.

---

Просьба не предлагать варианты, которые могут быть ассоциированы с политическими событиями или персонами. Такие варианты будут отклонены. Придерживайтесь максимально нейтральной формулировки. [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

**Обновление**

Одна из фраз была снята с голосования по результатам [обсуждения в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35299959#35299959), в связи с возможным негативным политическим контекстом.

Comment: [Целую всех вас, ваша тётя Агата.](https://www.anekdot.ru/id/-10086065/)

Comment: Мммммм... в голову приходит только "Всем чмоке в этом чатике". (...на этом сайтике) Нет уж, пусть в этом месте останется нелокализованным: "С уважением, команда Stack Exchange"

Comment: Предлагаю под карбонкопию спросить в наших языковых сообществах: [раз](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), [два](http://russian.stackexchange.com/), [три](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Спросил в [russian-SE](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/13916/8353) и [rus-SE](http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/429898/182097), может что дельного подскажут. Одна голова хорошо, а три -- Змей Горыныч ;)

Comment: Нелокализованным - это оставить XOXO, а не убить шутку сухим "с уважением". Котика на 500-й тоже предлагаю не переводить :)

Comment: @PashaPash Было б где на другой странице... А тут у тебя проблемы со входом и какие-то шуточки. Не уверен, что это так уж уместно.

Comment: Предлагаю "Yippee ki-yay, mother*#@cker"

Comment: Не помешало б еще поменять "Login в настоящее время недоступно".

Comment: @andreycha оно само подхватится, правда, скорее всего в неудачной форме "Войти в настоящее время недоступно" из-за склейки строк.

Comment: Т.е. чуваки сэкономили на строчках и склеили эту фразу из нескольких? Жесть :))).

Comment: @andreycha Вы можете сами в этом убедиться в transifex. Подобные случаи не редкость. Уже заменяли склейку на самостоятельные фразы в некоторых местах. Может и до сюда дело дойдет.

Comment: Да я верю. Просто склейка -- не самый удачный подход, если ты собираешь локализовывать приложение.

Comment: Принимай ответ уже)

Comment: @Qwertiy я уже принимал ответ один раз. Хватит :)

Comment: @alexolut, пора снова. Пока его по какой-нибудь причине не удалили)))

Comment: @Qwertiy получите, распишитесь!

Comment: @alexolut, а что сломать чтобы проверить?

Comment: @Qwertiy попросить PashaPash объединить вопросы, например.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сильно отклонюсь от оригинала, но предложу такое:

> Не переключайтесь,
>   команда StackExchange

По крайней мере для меня эта фраза звучит максимально позитивно.

Окраску в неё вкладывает употребление радио-/теле-ведущими, которые этим намекают, что дальше тоже будет интересно. Это приблизительно соответствует тому, что у нас.

Comment: Утвердил на [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/106501778?key=a0cda30904822f49019a6219c0a16287). Будет доступно после обновления базы строк, пересборки сайта и ... последующего за этим падения серверов :)

Answer (score 7):

Что насчёт такого варианта:

> Чмоки,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.

Парадигмы для этого слова пока нет в словарях ([только как междометие](http://opencorpora.org/dict.php?act=edit&id=376864)), на мой взгляд это существительное в именительном падеже множественного числа.

Да, как-то так:

[image: парадигма]

Comment: Винительный падеж мн.ч. - Чмоков. Я послал Вам тысячу чмоков!

Comment: Творительный падеж - Кем? Чем? Чмоком, Чмоками.

Comment: @Mae Винительный -- это я вижу (кого? что?) чмоки, а у вас родительный: я послал вам тысячу (кого? чего?) чмоков. С творительным -- да, накладка вышла и ведь никто даже и не заметил! )

Comment: Всячески поддерживаю. Именно так и переводится - "чмоки" (им.п., мн.ч.)

Answer (score 7):

Или даже так:

> С пламенным приветом,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.

Comment: Во, отличная версия! Настоящий, с душой перевод.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем общий ответ? Отказ от баллов за [meta-tag:локализация]? =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Я думал, что если я сделаю ответ общим мне дадут возможность понажимать на upvote/downvote. Однако, система по-прежнему помнит, что это мой ответ: "нельзя голосовать за или против своего сообщения". Эх, буду знать.

Comment: ага, нельзя так. Могу вернуть ответы в собственность.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ну поголосовать-то я за них всё равно не смогу, так что не надо. И они в основном заминусованные ))

Answer (score 4):

Вариант:

> Целуем, обнимаем,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант:

> Крепко обнимаем,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Ммммм, можно просто:

> С приветом,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.

Comment: Возникает ощущение как будто команда SE признаётся в том, что "с приветом":)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov считаете, это не может быть правдой?

Answer (score 0):

А почему обязательно нужно передать это буквально? Это скорее шуточный "вариант" подписи в конце того же письма или документа. ИМХО, в переводе на русский язык лучше всего будет отдать предпочтение более нейтральному варианту, который в какой-то степени несет ту же положительную коннотацию, например:

> С наилучшими пожеланиями

Comment: Это хочется передать со смыслом. Не обязательно буквально.

Comment: @alexolut Так смысл то как раз в "Наилучших пожеланиях", по мне это более уместный вариант, чем "чатовский"  чмоки, обнимашки и пр.

Comment: Привёл форматирование к общему виду.

Answer (score -1):

Давайте не будем это переводить один-в-один, оставим нейтрально-вежливое:

> С уважением,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.

Как минимум -- пока не придумаем более подходящий перевод.

Answer (score -1):

Вариант:

> Жмём руку,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

Альтернативная версия, т.н. "падонкаффский йезык":

> Чмоке,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -2):

Ещё версия:

> С рабочим приветом,
>
> команда Stack Exchange.