# Полезны ли вопросы-картинки и как можно улучшить ситуацию?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

[Довольно часто встречаю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9) вопросы о <s>гадании по фотографии</s> вёрстке по картинке. Они выглядят примерно так:

```
object = random (список, лендинг, блок, фон, страницу, кнопку...)
```

> ### Как правильно сверстать такой %object%?
>
> [image]

<sub>Автор изображения: [Aokoroko](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Aokoroko) - собственная работа, [CC BY-SA 4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), [Ссылка](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=56722698)</sub>

---

Основная проблема здесь в том, что картинки не индексируются поисковиками, а текста, описывающего проблему автора, в вопросе нет.

На мой взгляд, в такой формулировке ответы на них бесполезны всем, кроме автора вопроса — следовательно, в масштабе всего сайта, бесполезны чуть менее чем полностью.

Предлагаю подумать, как улучшить ситуацию. По моему мнению, задачи такие:

- Сделать так, чтобы проблема в таких вопросах точно описывалась текстом и индексировалась поисковиками.
- При этом не оттолкнуть экспертов по технологиям, связанным с версткой. (Заметьте, что меня не беспокоят спрашивающие: если мы улучшим индексацию, их поток точно вырастет).
- Заодно выйти из порочного круга хелп-вампиризма: перестать делать разовые заказы, которые больше никому не будут полезны.

Comment: 1. эта ситуация довольна схожа с часто встречающимися в вопросах скриншотами вместо текста. 2. возможные выходы: а) попросить автора написать словами; б) сделать это самому.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin  «сделать это самому» плохо масштабируется. Надо бы научить авторов делать правильно, а не править за ними. Наверное, нужно сделать какую-то инструкцию. Если они умеют только картинками общаться — а такой вывод напрашивается — то инструкцию с гифками, комикс, обучающий мультфильм. Я в растерянности, если честно.

Comment: можно зайти с другой стороны, глобальной — добавить в процесс игрофикации — ввести возможность давать оценку **правке** вопроса/ответа.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin бывает, что вместо нормального названия ставят формальное.

Comment: связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4692

Answer (score 8):

Вы подняли очень сложную тему, но попробую описать свои предложения.

Самое первое и очевидное. Картинки нужно описывать текстом. Без вариантов.

Очевидные трудности здесь -- это то, что авторы не хотят эту работу делать и без этой работы найдутся доброхоты, которые дадут ответ и без этого. Нужна воля сообщества, чтобы закрывать вопросы без текста, чтобы невозможно было дать ответ. Есть ли она?

Далее. Можно поощрять работу тех, кто правит за автора описания. Вручную (автоматических способов не приходит в голову) выдавать медальки за хорошие описания. Явный плюс -- это будет очень редкая медалька, как 'No robots'.

В составлении описаний нужно наработать какую-то типовую базу. Это как составление словесного портрета преступника: нужно научиться выделять значимые и важные черты, уметь опускать всё незначительное. Возможно, придётся нарабатывать на ходу, по мере возникновения вопросов.

Далее. Я считаю, что нужен какой-то особый тег, который нужно будет выделить для целей картиночных вопросов и форсить его до тех пор, пока он не станет стандартом де-факто и на so, и на других сайтах и в ИТ в целом, чтобы потом не только мы его продвигали, но любой новичок, пришедший в отрасль, знал этот термин. Цель сложная, но под стать сложности самого вопроса.

Даже если мы зафейлимся по направлению "описывать текстом" можно будет заставить перебирать пользователя тег, хоть какая-то возможность поиска.

Далее. Обязательно нужно составлять базу хороших вопросов по этой теме и нещадно заносить в FAQ этой метки. (Тут хотел вставить ссылку на вопрос про текст треугольником, но разумеется не нашёл. А, [вот он](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549173/213987), спасибо Grundy). Вопросы из FAQ как правило получают больше плюсов и месяцы спустя, это хороший стимул работать над ними.

И последнее. Пиарить тему через проведение конкурсов по 50 баллов на вопрос.

У меня всё. Прошу высказываться в комментариях.

Comment: *найдутся доброхоты, которые дадут ответ и без этого* — вот такому «доброхоту» и следует вменить в обязанность привести вопрос в порядок. «морковка» — «плюсики» и медальки ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/90/explainer), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/91/refiner), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/92/illuminator)), «кнут» — «минусы». // надо только осветить это в виде вопросо-ответа на мете или статьи в правилах, чтобы можно было ссылку «доброхоту» давать.

Comment: *какой-то особый тег* — «наскальная живопись», «демотиватор», «книжка-раскраска», «внимание на экран» (аллюзия к «что? где? когда?»), «вопрос-картинка»

Comment: @alexanderbarakin можно открыть отдельную тему в которую кидать варианты и голосовать за них, как это было с [xoxo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4720/213987)

Answer (score 5):

Внесу свои 5 копеек, тк иной раз сам использую картинки в вопросах или ответах.

Прежде всего если `текста, описывающего проблему автора, в вопросе нет.` то автор вопроса однозначно не хочет думать сам, вероятно уверенный во всесильных и все-сострадательных старожилах форума, которые не только поймут смысл но и не поленятся на него ответить. Очень редко(никогда) бывают ситуации когда картинка говорит сама за себя. Однако если скрин является только приложением к основному тексту, то видимо автор наоборот хотел облегчить понимание вопроса, что вполне допустимо и даже похвально.

Далее, о предложении : `Сделать так, чтобы проблема в таких вопросах точно описывалась текстом` тут вариант только один - сначала тактичное замечание, затем, если результата ноль - удаление вопроса.

Ну и последнее - `перестать делать разовые заказы` а это уже должен решать сам человек. Я имею в виду, что можно ввести правила - **как задавать вопросы** но нельзя контролировать **как давать ответы**. Можно запретить публикацию вопросов не имеющих смысла или сформированных одной картинкой, но давать на него ответ или нет решить может только тот кто сидит по ту сторону экрана. И конечно каждый случай может быть исключением, так что лекарства от всех болезней мы никогда не найдем. Как то так.

Comment: «удаление вопроса» — ну это жестко слишком. Есть механизм «требует правки» — на вопрос нельзя отвечать, если автор его улучшает, то становится снова можно.

Comment: Вопрос всегда можно задать снова, но уже поправленным. Удаление - серьезная мера, но и более действенная.

Comment: Удалять жёстко? Тогда нужно закрывать вопрос ДО того, как появляется ответ. Тем, кто не хочет думать сам как правило крайне важно получить ответ быстро, мы же сейчас говорим о том, что мы думаем, как и ДРУГИМ сделать полезно, то есть нам некритично, что висит закрытый вопрос.

Comment: @AK это невозможно, для закрытия нужно собрать 5 голосов, либо один решающий голос модератора (которые не всегда онлайн, и не всегда могут мгновенно реагировать), либо же голос самого автора (который вряд ли захочет закрывать свой вопрос).

Comment: *нельзя контролировать как давать ответы* — [отчасти можно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5298#comment19722_5302).

Comment: @NickVolynkin недостаточно просто улучшения, надо чтобы потом ещё за переоткрытие пятеро проголосовали ведь.

Comment: @alexolut я же упрощаю.

Answer (score 3):

[*найдутся доброхоты, которые дадут ответ и без этого*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5302/178576) (т.е., без текстового описания картинки) — вот такого «доброхота» и следует поощрять привести вопрос в порядок.

«морковка» имеется — «голос за (ответ)» и «медальки» ([толкователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/90/explainer), [наставник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/91/refiner), [просветитель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/92/illuminator)).

ести и «кнут» — «голос против (ответа)».

надо только осветить всё это либо в виде вопроса на мете, либо статьи в правилах (желательно, [простым языком](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5279/178576)), чтобы, приведя ссылку, можно было быстро и коротко объяснить «доброхоту», что ему стоит сделать для улучшения ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Заметил, что иногда такие вопросы, могут быть вполне даже годными. Поэтому по возможности старайтесь редактировать такие вопросы, а не закрывать. Закрывать лучше всё же в крайнем случае. Лучше подобные вопросы редактировать, чем закрывать. Так как отправив его на закрытие, его вы потратите время на его закрытие (время проверяющих в очереди), ответ либо удалится, либо будет висить закрытым. Если он будет висеть закрытым, то не будет возможности на него отвечать, и в лучшем случае, кто-то прийдёт и его кто-то отредактирует, затем снова траты времени на его переоткрытие.

---

Поэтому если можете, пожалуйста, просто подберите адекватные слова, описывающие данную картинку, чем отправьте его на закрытие.

Comment: это замечательный совет. к сожалению, не всегда можно им воспользоваться, например, не являясь специалистом в области верстки, нельзя считать, что изображённое на картинке, т.е., суть вопроса, понято верно. потому имеет смысл поступить более разумно и продуктивно: отметить вопрос как некачественный. чтобы он попал в очередь на проверку и, в самом «плохом» варианте, когда вопрос был бы закрыт, если бы никто из специалистов не внёс правку, её, возможно, всё-таки внёс бы сам автор вопроса.