# Что именно считать оскорбительным в вопросе?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, тревоги

Господа,в разделе "Тревога", есть такой раздел "невежливый или оскорбительный", по ссылке можно ознакомиться с [описанием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).  Приводить примеры матерных выражений или оскорбительных слов, естественно не буду, все мы взрослые, знаем, умеем... Это естественно и есть прямое оскорбление, а как быть с вопросами, которые не несут пользы сайту и сообществу и сайту и на мой взгляд оскорбляют всех.  Это вопросы не просто без [кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736950/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/736951?noredirect=1#comment1123421_736951) (примера) или [скриншота](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5298/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E), эти темы обсуждались на "мете" уже и не раз. На мой взгляд, оскорблением можно и нужно считать вопросы от участников, которые считают данный сайт, бесплатным фрилансом, которые не хотят развиваться, а просто вот именно сейчас им надо получить ответ и все  и только для себя. Получили ответ и все сгинули. Некоторые и ответ принять не хотят. Согласен, могут не знать или не уметь, сам был такой, спрашивал, как вопрос принять. Но если бы они заходили хотя бы раз в неделю, то понимали бы суть сайта его предназначение, но увы, я думаю, что им не надо. А новички за гонкой сбора баллов, отвечают на такие вопросы, не задумываясь, что это, намой взгляд, не хорошо.  Хочу предложить такой вариант ограничений, если в вопросе нет [минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), то участник форума со статусом малым количеством баллов, а сколько именно решать не мне, не мог бы на него отвечать, а если у участника, который задает вопрос со статусом меньше 100 баллов, что бы у него вообще не было бы возможности получить ответ, так как будет отсутствовать форма для ответа, пока не получит одобрение модератора или не пройдет проверку...

Итог, данного вопроса, в том, что я считаю оскорблением не только прямое словесное оскорбления личности, а еще и то, что время от времени появляются субъекты, которые не хотят нести пользу сообществу и думают только о себе...

P.S. Уверен, сейчас получу кучу просьб и требований конкретных примеров...  Увольте, примеров куча, как минимум каждый день встречаются, все видели и все знают.

Comment: Всё упирается в личный порог обидчивости.

Comment: По поводу запрета на ответ - частично именно эту проблему и решает очередь Triage на enSO.

Comment: @Other, Уверяю, я не обидчев))))))

Comment: Но оскорбляет такое поведение. Оно, конечно, плохое, но считать это оскорблением...

Comment: Предположим, я граммар-наци и меня оскорбляют орфографические и пунктуационные ошибки. Я только что прочитал этот вопрос и в нём вы меня оскорбили с десяток раз. Можно я отмечу вопрос как оскорбительный?

Comment: А потом придёт другой человек, которого оскорбляет слово «наци» и он  отметит мой комментарий как оскорбительный. А тревогу обработает модератор, который считает оскорблением, когда его отвлекают по таким пустякам.

Comment: К чему я это: давайте не будем искусственно расширять границы «оскорблений», иначе люди будут злоупотреблять тревогами из личной неприязни и перестанут доверять друг другу.

Comment: `"...а просто вот именно сейчас им надо получить ответ и все и только для себя..."` -- а мне кажется, что в первую очередь как раз для этого и нужен SO (и прочие подобные сайты).

Answer (score 3):

Всякими закрытиями и так злоупотребляют. Ещё предлагаешь начать злоупотреблять банами и стобальными штрафами? Нет, я против.

Comment: Поддерживаю, отписался подробнее в комментариях к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Оскорблением считается употребление слов, недопустимых в приличном обществе, или выражение негативного отношения к людям или группам людей. Вопрос "Какой либой на jquery реализовать сферического коня в вакууме" не является оскорблением, как бы усердно вы не пытались убедить себя в этом. Это просто некачественный вопрос от новичка, не понимающего как работает сайт. Средство для решения этой проблемы уже существует: это "минусы". Если вопрос заминусуют, он пропадет с главной страницы, и при активной ловле минусов участнику прилетит бан на задание новых вопросов.

Так что проблемы нет. Видите плохой вопрос — ставьте минус. Если он не по теме / слишком общий — также можно поставить тревогу. Если есть желание — напишите комментарий, объясняющий автору, как правильно задавать вопросы. Не стоит вступать в перепалку в комментариях к ответам других участников, просто пытающихся помочь, как вы сделали в вопросе по ссылке. Не нужно проявлять элитизм и устраивать мифическую борьбу с "ленивыми студентами", это не приведет ни к чему хорошему. Будьте конструктивны, и все будет нормально.

Comment: `Средство для решения этой проблемы уже существует` – минусы и баны не решают проблему, они её только скрывают с глаз долой. Новичков нужно обучать, нужен onboarding.

Comment: @NickVolynkin когда question ban выдают, вроде "жертве" выдается сообщение с ссылкой на faq по заданию вопросов? Где то на meta SE скрины видел.

Comment: Хм, не знал про это. Есть шаблон сообщения от модератора с коллекцией ссылок, но он не автоматически отправляется.

Comment: @NickVolynkin точнее даже до бана, вот: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/370389