# Специальная метка для вопросов-картинок

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, вопросы

Тех, кто не знаком с предысторией — прошу предварительно прочитать вопрос [Полезны ли вопросы-картинки и как можно улучшить ситуацию?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5298/213987), там же есть как примеры [типовых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9) вопросов, так и отдельные весьма любопытные образцы ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549173/213987), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760232/213987)).

В качестве одной из мер по улучшению ситуации я предлагал создать отдельную метку для подобного рода вопросов. Текущая тема — как раз попытка сконцентрироваться на этом предложении.

Предлагаю всем желающим высказаться по этой теме.

Если кто-то хочет предложить свой вариант метки — пишет ответ, чтобы остальные желающие могли проголосовать за/против при помощи кнопок upvote/downvote.

> Строго придерживаемся принципа "один вариант метки — отдельный
>   ответ".

Помимо голосования за отдельные версии — можно высказать отношение к созданию тега в целом:

- upvote вопроса считается голосованием "отдельная метка для подобных вопросов нужна"
- downvote вопроса соответственно — "отдельная метка для подобных вопросов не нужна"

Comment: Голосование какое-то неправильное. Downvote вопроса должно быть "такие вопросы недопустимы **или** им не нужна метка", upvote вопроса - "такие вопросы допустимы **и** им нужна метка".

Comment: @PavelMayorov допустимость подобных вопросов логичнее вынести в отдельное голосование: я предполалгал, что здесь только выбор метки обсуждаем, а сами вопросы допустимы. Что в них такого недопустимого? Как сверстать -- обычный вопрос для сайта, вполне онтопичный. Да, с ними есть морока -- они так себе ищутся поиском, но по этой причине их выкидывать из онтопика -- такое мне даже в голову не приходило.

Comment: А зачем нам вообще нужна подобная метка?

Answer (score 2):

метка [как-сверстать-такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5)

Comment: ТОже что-то слишком универсальное.

Answer (score 1):

уже сейчас мы назваем эти вопросы "вопросы-картинки", так и назовём: [вопросы-картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: А сюда вопросы со скриншотами кода попадать не будут?

Comment: @Qwertiy IMHO -- будут попадать и это будет нехорошо.

Comment: Надо как-то конкретизироваться, но я пока не пойму, как именно.

Answer (score -5):

можно назвать метку [нетривиальная-вёрстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0), чтобы подчеркнуть сложность вопросов.

Comment: Это более общая метка, не уверен, не будут ли ей злоупотреблять?

Answer (score -6):

[геометрическая-вёрстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) - отражает связь вёрстки с геомертическими фигурами.
Но не отражает наличие связи с картинками, ведь фон - это не геометрия.

Comment: Верстка всегда связана с геометрией, так что это тоже "масло маслянное".

Comment: Не считаю, что вёрстка - это геометрия. И вообще, там все вопросы геометрические.

Answer (score -6):

[графическая-вёрстка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) - отражает связь с графикой. Пожалуй, геометрические фигуры тоже можно назвать графикой, хотя и с некоторой натяжкой.

Comment: Бывает ли неграфическая вёрстка? Кажется, вёрстка по умолчанию это уже графика, получается "масло масленное".

Comment: И не будет ли ассоциироваться с фошотопом?