# Почему подобные вопросы по HTML CSS считаются хорошими?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Пример вопроса, который получил много плюсов и ни одного голоса "закрыть" по теме HTML CSS. [Как сделать такой радиальный прозрачный вырез?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1126088/212981)

А вот такой вопрос по C# WinForms считается плохим и получил 4 голоса за закрытие вопроса. [Как убрать у кнопки черные внешние границы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1129599/212981)

Мне кажется, что эти два вопроса по сути одинаковы. Оба вопроса по верстке. В обоих вопросах отражен ожидаемый результат и в обоих вопросах нет ни строчки кода. Тогда почему один вопрос считается плохим, а другой хорошим?.

Comment: потому что за один проголосовали 4 раза за закрытие, а за другой - нет.

Comment: Эти вопросы противоположны по сути. Первый — «Как сделать», второй — «Как сломать сделанное». Если написать вопрос вида «как здесь убрать границу» про HTML, то его точно так же закроют, потому что не предоставлен [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @andreymal почему же? У кнопки есть свойства ее стиля, изменив которые можно добиться желаемого результата. Да, я согласен с вами, что вопрос по верстке html-страницы - это вопрос «Как создать на основе инструментов», но второй вопрос, скорее, можно назвать «Как стилизовать существующий компонент»

Comment: @AndreiKhotko соответственно в вопросе должен быть предоставлен код этого самого существующего компонента, иначе можно только догадываться, что конкретно имеет в виду автор под словом «кнопка»

Comment: @andreymal, в общем случае да. Но в данном конкретном - совершенно нормально допустить что речь идет о компоненте Button в стиле Flat. Точнее говоря - по описанию и скриншоту это настолько очевидно, что просить код просто язык не поворачивается.

Comment: @Uranus в базе знаний ничего нельзя допускать, иначе это уже не база знаний, а сообщество вернувшихся с отпусков телепатов. "речь идет о компоненте Button в стиле Flat" - это обязано быть прописано автором в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @Uranus и не забываем про поисковые системы! Если ничего не написать про flat button, то будущие пользователи **не смогут нагуглить** этот вопрос. В итоге этот вопрос **вредит базе знаний** и просто категорически обязан быть закрыт до исправления автором. Докинул пятый голос за закрытие именно по этой причине.

Comment: @andreymal, это у меня просто такая манера общения - не люблю категорчных суждений и заменяю их на более мягкие :-) Изначально я хотел сказать категорично - в этом вопрое все понятно и никаких допущений не требуется.

Comment: @andreymal, замечание про Flat это все таки часть ответа. Потому что с точки зрения базы знаний полезен как раз более общий вопрос. Во первых, неопытный человек не в курсе про то, что в его вопросе имеет значение  FlatStyle. Во вторых, у других он будет другой, и им подойдет первый ответ, где советуют использовть PictureBox.

Comment: @Uranus если автор вопроса просит исправить компонент - он автоматически становится обязан предоставить код этого компонента. Вопросы без кода про исправление компонентов в HTML тоже всегда закрывают.

Comment: @Uranus для того, чтобы Flat стал частью ответа, необходимо полностью переписать вопрос в формат "Как сделать кликабельную картинку без бордера" - тогда и код будет не нужен, и закрывать никто не станет.

Comment: @andreymal, не бывает таких правил, которые работают всегда. В данном случае, большинство новичков сформулирую вопрос именно так - как убрать бордеры у кнопки (стандартного компонента) https://www.google.com/search?q=winforms+hide+button+border. Зачем все усложнять и обязывать кого-то добавлять в вопрос не нужную информацию ради соответствия каким-то формальным критериям?

Comment: @Uranus затем, что Stack Overflow не просто форум, а база знаний. А для нормальной работы базы знаний нужно оформлять тексты соответствующим образом, в том числе писать очевидные вещи, чтобы лучше гуглилось.

Comment: @andreymal, я и объясняю - данный текст оформлен наилучшим образом для данного конкретного случая. Если поставить себя на место новичка - я бы не стал искать код, в коде нет ничего специфичного этому вопросу. Я бы описал свою задачу - спрятать бордер. В другом случае я бы с вами согласился.

Comment: @Uranus спрятать бордер **где**? В вопросе не указано, что речь о стандартном компоненте кнопки. Ещё раз, очевидные вещи должны быть указаны, чтобы случайно не оказалось, что автор взял какую-то кастомную кнопку и забыл это упомянуть. Ну и чтобы людям без гугла было понятнее, что речь о стандартном компоненте, без разглядывания каких-то там картинок. Вам кнопка очевидна, мне — нет.

Comment: @andreymal, ну это WinForms, достаточно сказать что это кнопка или еще точнее Button. Если явно не указано что это самописный компонент, подразумевается что стандартный.

Comment: @Uranus ещё раз, не надо никаких подразумеваний в базе знаний, это излишне запутывает, не говоря уже о том, что подразумевания могут оказаться неверными. Кстати, обратите внимание, что по вашей же ссылке во втором результате в гугле явно написано про **Standard Button**.

Comment: @andreymal А  это отнюдь не в базе знания подразумевается - это вообще среди разработчиков WinForms принято под кнопкой подразумевать Button и ни что иное.

Comment: @Uranus а человек, который видит WinForms первый раз в жизни, может не знать никаких подразумеваний и умудриться сделать кнопку каким-то своим особым путём. Вдруг он уже скопипастил PictureBox из гугла и поставил на неё картинку с изначально нарисованным бордером и теперь жалуется? Откуда нам знать, что у человека в голове? Наличие кода исключит подобные недоразумения и заодно упростит гуглинг тем людям, которые гуглят конкретно стандартную кнопку без всяких PictureBox.

Comment: Не ломайте копья впустую. Все равно вопрос дубликат другого вопроса 4-летней давности: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537168/

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight и там тоже написано «Лучше бы вместо картинки код прилепили для наглядности» :)

Comment: @andreymal, вот это уже с вашей стороны пошли додумывания и подразумевания. Если база знаний будет рассчитана на подобных чудо экземпляров, которые используют одно, а гуглят другое, то она станет бесполезна для всех остальных

Comment: @Uranus вопросы от подобных чудо экземпляров тоже нужно править/закрывать. И от не-чудо экземпляров тоже надо править, чтобы было понятно, что они не-чудо. Явное лучше неявного, не надо никаких подразумеваний и догадываний, тогда и проблем никаких не возникнет в принципе.

Comment: Потому что в одном случае это вызов самому себе, а во втором - просто вопрос

Comment: Я считаю оба вопроса хороши, то что один закрыли — несправедливо и неправильно. Я голосую за переоткрытие.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica хммммм https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdpSr.png

Comment: @andreymal Да, вот что значит делать очередь проверок под вечер...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Полезны ли вопросы-картинки и как можно улучшить ситуацию?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5298/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На мой взгляд, оба вопроса нормальные и ни минусовать, ни закрывать их не следует.

Что касается ответа на вопрос "почему" - вероятно, потому что сделать круглый вырез сложно, а в winforms прописать ButtonStyle.Flat элементарно. Но это неправильный подход к минусованию и закрытию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Мне осталось непонятным лишь одно: когда подобного рода вопросы подпадают под пункт закрытия "учебные задания", а когда нет? Я думал, что любого рода вопрос "Как это сделать?" без попыток реализации от автора (в виде конкретного кода) подпадают под этот пункт.

Comment: Автор второго вопроса просит исправить проблему в его коде, но ни кода, ни даже намёка на то, как этот код может выглядеть (см. выше дисскусию про flat standard button), нет. Он однозначно должен быть закрыт.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko 1. Никогда. 2. Нет, про это есть куча тем на мете. 3. Эта причина вообще зло и не надо её использовать. Про это тоже есть куча тем на мете. 4. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: @andreymal, в каком коде? Он сделал несколько кликов в дизайнере форм, текстовый код в VS показывается пустым. Надо взять блокнот, открыть файл дизайнера и скопипастить оттуда пару десятков совершенно бесполезных строк, без которых вопрос абсолютно понятен?

Comment: @Qwertiy значит надо рассказать, какие клики были сделаны в дизайнере форм — вдруг там вместо кнопки уже PictureBox давным-давно накликан. Без этого вопрос абсолютно непонятен и проблема не является невоспроизводимой.

Comment: @Qwertiy я рад за вас с Uranus, что вы такие крутые опытные телепаты, но, пожалуйста, не нужно превращать базу знаний в ресурс, пригодный для чтения только такими же телепатами.

Comment: @andreymal, вопрос абсолютно понятен и та фигня, которую ты хочешь в него напихать, является лишь бесполезным загромождением вопроса. И я уже минимум третий человек, который тебе об этом говорит даже в пределах этой страницы.

Comment: @Qwertiy я рад за этих минимум трёх телепатов, но см. мой предыдущий комментарий

Comment: @Qwertiy и с каких это пор фраза «Button с FlatStyle=Flat» стала бесполезным загромождением вопроса? Вас Чехов со своей сестрой таланта покусал?

Comment: @andreymal, `FlatStyle=Flat` - это же ответ. В вопросе Button с Background без дополнительных стилей.

Comment: @andreymal, хотя нет, посмотрел внимательнее - на скриншоте уже Flat, тогда да, согласен, про него стоило в вопросе написать.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот о том и речь. Сейчас вопрос фактически является гаданием по картинке и понятен только тем, кто уже вызубрил внешний вид Flat с точностью до пикселей и уверен, что никаким другим способом такой же вид получить нельзя (а я вот не уверен, например)

Comment: @andreymal, есть подозрение, что при редактировании FlatAppearance в дизайнере автоматически включится Flat, хотя я не проверял. В любом случае, в ответе они названы оба.

Comment: @Qwertiy в любом случае, ответ начинается со слова «Если», что автоматически подразумевает, что он может оказаться не очень-то и верным

Answer (score 0):

В целом, вопросы как вопросы. И такое вроде не запрещено, если есть хотя бы какое-то описание текстом.

Другое дело ответы на те вопросы, что вы привели. В текущем виде они совершенно не качественные, никуда не годятся. Просто какая-то портянка без единого комментария. Непосвящённому с первого взгляда трудно понять, как тот код работает. А ведь цель нашего ресурса — научить читателя чему-то новому. Ответы в подобном формате эту задачу не решают, и потому имеют низкую ценность.

Comment: Иногда (подчеркиваю - иногда), код нагляднее слов. Чаще всего тогда, когда попытка объяснить решение сводится к пересказу кода человеческими словами. Учит ли код чему-то новому? Да, безусловно может. Нужно всего два условия: 1) Ты этого раньше не знал (того чему учит); 2) Ты код изучаешь, а не копируешь из ответа. С CSS решениями проще всего - банально открываешь инспектор, и по очереди вырубаешь правила чтобы понять, каким образом возник необходимый эффект.