# Насколько быстро вы голосуете за закрытие вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Давно замечаю такую вещь, что плохо оформленные вопросы очень быстро набирают голоса за закрытия и минусы. Сегодня просто под горчую руку попался [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1482693/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вопроса уже 4 голоса за закрытие (там где специфичная причина, выбран вариант с отладкой программы) и 3 минуса. По выбранным причинам насколько я понимаю, все они были сделаны ДО прикрепеления фото

Если смотреть на историю изменений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то можно увидеть что вопрос задан в `10:44`, просьба о том, чтобы автор прикрепил свои старания было в `10:50` и уже в `10:54` была добавлена фото. Т.е. прошло всего 10 минут, а уже вопрос на грани закрытия

Не думайте что тут осуждаю кого-то или утверждаю что так делать нельзя. Нет, каждый сам решает когда за что голосовать и ставить минус

Я лично дорожу своим голосом т.к. я могу его выставить единожды (если не считать голос за переоткрытие), потому оставляю обычно такие вопросы в другой вкладке и возвращаюсь примерно через час ну или когда вспомню о вопросе и почти всегда заранее пишу причину по которой собираюсь голосвать за закрытие. Если автор никак не реагирует, то уже голосую за закрытие по заранее указанной причине. Минус например в отличии от голоса, могу выставить сразу, т.к. это действие легко отменяется + автору идёт уведомление об уменьшении репутации

Тут нет никакого правильного ответа, просто интересно, кто когда голосует и почему? Возможно моё мнение изменится после вашх ответов :)

Comment: Я вообще не закрываю вопросов (кроме откровенного бреда), относящихся к IT

Comment: @avp Вы у нас ярый сторонник не закрывать вообще никакие вопросы :)

Comment: Да, я считаю, что труднообратимые действия надо делать как можно реже.  А если делаешь что-то такое, то надо  хорошо обдумать все последствия. Понятно, что хорошо обдумывать вопросы на SO никакого смысла нет.

Comment: ruSo давно превратился в сервис по закрыванию вопросов,а не в сервис для ответов на них. если вы не согласны с такой позицией, можете написать об этом на мете и там с вами сделают что-нибудь аналогичное

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Чем дольше живёт платформа тем больше будет повторяющихся или почти таких же вопросов которые были уже заданы, и чем больше таких вопросов тем больше будет доля закрытых вопросов. Это просто естественный порядок вещей. Вот выйдет завтра что-то типа `NewJS` и будут по нему 500 новых вопросов, на которые будут отвечать, а не закрывать, но с течением времени, один спросит что-то типа "А как кнопку сделать красной?" и его закроют дубликатом на "А как кнопку сделать синей?". Ну на счёт плохо оформленных вопросов и по вопросам не по теме думаю всё понятно

Comment: А зачем закрывать повторы? Может лучше (гуманней, если угодно), найдя повтор, отредактировать вопросы, добавив туда ссылки друг на друга? Надеюсь, почему это лучше всем понятно (хотя и соглашусь, что это более хлопотно)

Comment: @avp Так закрытие дубликтом и так оставляет ссылку на дубликат. И вы же понимаете, что если 5 вопросов являются дубликатами 1-ого вопроса, то логично только у 5-ти вопросов оставить ссылку на 1, и не добавлять 5 ссылок на этот 1 нечастный вопрос :)

Comment: На самом деле, на практике это абсолютно нелогично, т.к. вопросы могут различаться в неких деталях,  которые будут по разному разбираться в разных ответах (конечно, это работает только при достаточно количестве активно отвечающих (на замечание, что таких у нас мало, могу предположить, что это как раз следствие текущей политики закрытия дубликатов))

Comment: @avp Я не понял, елси честно. Если воспросы отличаются в деталях, то пусть у них и будет ссылка на тот вопрос, от которого они отличаются, зачем в основном вопросе плодить список всех вопросов, которые на него хоть как-то похожи?

Comment: В общем, то это я все к тому, что просто не надо закрывать вопросы (обсуждать все детали границ желания нет)

Answer (score 2):

Все голосуют по-разному. Но чем хуже вопрос и чем меньше его наполнение и оформление соответствует принятым нормам SO, тем быстрее он будет заминусован и/или закрыт.

Возможно, кто-то готов отложить принятия решения о голосе за закрытие и дать автору время на улучшение/исправление вопроса. Но для этого надо самому обладать этим временем, а потом ещё не забыть вернуться к вопросу, чтобы проверить изменилась ли ситуация к лучшему или нет.

В случае с упомянутым вопросом всё произошло быстро т.к.:

- исходно было не видно усилий автора в попытке решения проблемы
- позже был опубликован код картинкой ([что противоречит местным традициям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5298/176217))
- вопрос недостаточно понятно описан

Всё это можно списать на то, что автор здесь новичок, а порог вхождения на сайт, чтобы хорошо сформулировать вопрос, достаточно высок. Чтобы это как-то сгладить придумали плашки "Новый участник" (видно на вашем скриншоте), но на неё не всегда обращают внимание те, кто голосуют.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен, но что происхожит в целом я вкурсе, меня интересует мнение каждого по тодельности. Судя по причинам закрытия, я преполагаю что голоса за закрытие поступили до того как была добавлена картинка + намного чаще вижу, чтобы просили код вставлять текстом вместо картинки, а не голосуют за закрытие. Вот вы лично как поступаете и почему? Расскажите это пожалуйста :)

Comment: @EzioMercer я так и поступаю, как описал.

Comment: "Все голосуют по-разному", "Возможно, кто-то готов отложить...", "на неё не всегда обращают внимание те, кто голосуют" - если честно не очень понятно как конкретно вы поступаете :)

Comment: @EzioMercer у меня нет какого-то четкого алгоритма